# PHP copy file without changing the last modified date

Tags: php, file, date, copy

According to the comment in PHP manual about Copy(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

The copy() will change the last modified date of the destination file.

Is there a way that a file can be copied without updating the last modified date??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way that a file can be copied without updating the last modified date??

Probably not, but you can use [`touch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) to modify the time back to your desired value.

Comment: Thanks. With copy() + touch() + filemtime(), it takes ~30% longer than just copy().

Answer (score 20):

```
function copydt($pathSource, $pathDest) {   // copy(), same modification-time
    copy($pathSource, $pathDest) or return FALSE;
    $dt = filemtime($pathSource);
    if ($dt === FALSE) return FALSE;
    return touch($pathDest, $dt);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use filemtime() to get last modified date and then touch() for modifying last modified date/time

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion from the PHP documentation annotations for 'copy' suggests using the exec() command to invoke 'xcopy' to perform the copy.  This worked for me, but I like the copy/touch solution better.  I am comparing mtimes already, so no performance lag added for that.  I haven't tried it, but I assume that 'cp' will work on *nix.