# keep modify date old one when File Upload with PHP to new folder

Tags: php

**html:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'];

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$path = $upload_dir."/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if( isset( $_POST ) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" )
{
  // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
  foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name )
  {     
      if ( $_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4 )
      {
          continue; // Skip file if any error found
      }        
      if ( $_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0 )
      {
          if( ! in_array( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ), $valid_formats ) )
          {
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
          }
          else
          {
                // Move uploaded files. 
                if( copy( $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name ) )
                $count++;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I want to keep the modify date old which is right now is `16 December 2014`. But when that file moves to new folder using above code, the modify date of the file (in the new folder) changed to current date i.e `13 January 2015`.
Is there any way to reserve the modify date or created date when uploading the file to new folder?

[image: <code>Sample</code>]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4898534/2752041). You'll probably need to fetch last modified date with `filemtime()` and after moving it you'll need to change the modified date using `touch()`

Comment: can you tell me how to fetch the modified date using above code? what if I upload multiple files at once?