# PHP - Download file and preserve timestamp?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, last-modified

As the name suggests, is there a quick way to download a file, but bring the timestamp along?

I'm writing a basic cache that, among other checks, determines (via `get_headers`) if a given local file is the same as it's remote counterpart.

I know I can `file_get_contents` / `file_put_contents` and then `touch()` the file with the results of `get_headers`, but the calling that is making another HTTP call (even if it is a HEAD call) and I'd only like to test Last-Modified as a last resort.

So is there a quick, "one HTTP call" way to download a file and preserve the timestamp? Some remote files live on an FTP server, but many are text files, and / or live on a web server.

EDIT: Someone suggested a related question, but my question differs, in that I'm looking to get the remote modified date without having to make a second call, which the `copy()` based answer suggests

`$http_response_header` seems to do the trick, as suggested below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP copy file without changing the last modified date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898534/php-copy-file-without-changing-the-last-modified-date)

Comment: As you already highlight "Download" is quite a generic term. For instance, the web server can choose to send `Last-Modified` or not, and even if it does there's no warantee it'll mean anything (what if it's a script rather than a static file?)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Too right. However because I know that the server I'm working with always returns Last-Modified, I'm happy to rely on it. The files I'm accessing are time-sensitive (Aurora Australis / Borealis data) so that's an extra reason for them to send Last-Modified headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get cached `Last-Modified` from [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) and use it to touch the file.

To automate it completely is obviously not possible as the stream cannot know where are you going to store it.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the trick! I've modified my code to check this variable, and `touch()` the file with the retrieved timestamp. Now my cache is working as expected, as a re-download is skipped if the remote and local timestamps match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filemtime() to get last modified date and then touch() for modifying last modified date/time

Source: [PHP copy file without changing the last modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898534/php-copy-file-without-changing-the-last-modified-date)

Comment: Please note this depends on the wrapper and not all of them support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_exists($cache_file) && (filemtime($cache_file) > (time() - 60 * 5 ))) {
   // Cache file is less than five minutes old. 
   // Don't bother refreshing, just use the file as-is.
   $file = file_get_contents($cache_file);
} else {
   // Our cache is out-of-date, so load the data from our remote server,
   // and also save it over our cache for next time.
   $file = file_get_contents($url);
   file_put_contents($cache_file, $file, LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: You can write into file when onclick is performed