# keep last modified date when uploading file

Tags: php, date, post, upload

Is there a way to preserve the last modified date when uploading a file via HTTP POST?

I already read that it gets changed when you use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898534/php-copy-file-without-changing-the-last-modified-date)).
But in my case, it's already changed in the temp folder.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file to upload:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  echo "Modified: ".date('d/m/Y H:i:s', filemtime($_FILES['fileToUpload']["tmp_name"]));

?>
```

The output is: *Modified: 17/02/2016 09:02:39*

But the file is actually last edited on 10/02/2016 09:34:23

Properties: (created, modified, access)

[image: file properties]

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: There is nothing you can do. The file is getting newly created on your server and then the OS sets the attribute. It does not copy the attribute.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois And is there a way to read the date and set it back to the old?

Comment: `But in my case, it's already changed in the temp folder` - it's not changed, it's _created_ with current timestamp. File in `uploads/` and file in temp folder are _different_ files, there is no reason for os to mark file in temp folder with timestamp of file from upload folder. You should follow @Mr.Engineer advice: 1) get timestamp of file in upload folder with `filemtime()` 2) copy file from temp folder to upload folder with `copy()` 2) set timestamp of copied file in upload folder with `touch()`

Comment: @ankhzet Please note that the file is not existing on the server yet. The `uploads/` folder is empty. The uploaded file is a new one. I do not want to replace it with another file.

Comment: @Vince, then `I already read that it gets changed when you use copy()` is meaningless. File upload doesn't transports magically some physical electrones from file on yours local machine to server. It creates new file on the server (thus, its `mtime` is set to current time), and fills it with contents of file, transmitted by user browser/other client-app.

Comment: In order to mark file on server with timestamp of that file on user machine, you must implicitly inform server about that timestamp. That can be done via JavaScript [File.lastModifiedDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModifiedDate) api, but it have somewhat limited browser compability.

Comment: @ankhzet Oh, okay. I'll try it with javascript. That should do the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm grappling with this as well. I'm probably going to resort to reading the date modified on the client side and sending that data along on the post request to my server.

Answer (score 2):

The last modified date can be captured in the browser using the File.lastModified property.  You can use JavaScript to set the value of a hidden input element to this date.  Once the form is submitted, read the timestamp from the hidden input and use the method `touch` to set the timestamp on the newly created file on the server-side.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified

https://www.php.net/touch

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you cannot keep the file information. The uploaded file is considered as new file.