# How to find the created/modified time of a client file from HTML Web App?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to design a Web App with upload function based on HTML and PHP.

I use the `<input type="file">` method to select files. When I tried to upload, I find that the file modified time is changed. I tried several ways to get the modified time of the original file but no luck.

`_Files` array do not include the 'modified time'.

`_FILES['input_name']['tmp_name']` is the path to the tmp file for upload, it is not the original file.

`stat()` cannot be used as the browser is not allow to get the path of the original file due to the security reason.

However, I can upload a file to Google Drive using Browser and the Properties on Google Drive is same as the original file. How do they do that?

If the browser block the HTML input method, do I have other choice to upload files and maintain the modified time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keep last modified date when uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451077/keep-last-modified-date-when-uploading-file)

Comment: Haha, I have read this post before I post the question.

Answer (score 0):

use the **filemtime** inbuilt function in php

```
<?php
 $last_modified = filemtime("gfg.txt"); // when echoed : 1525159574
 $convert_time_to_datetime = date("F d Y H:i:s", $last_modified);
 echo $convert_time_to_datetime; // May 1 2018 07:26:14
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer my question... The gfg.txt is hardcoded in your answer but I want to let user select files to upload.

Comment: you can enter the file path instead of gfg.txt

Comment: Yes, I can set up an input box for user to paste the real path of file manually. However, I want that user can select the files and get the real path automatically.

Comment: i am not really sure of your php upload method but i would advise to use this code strictly https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp and after the file name is stored in the DB, the filename from the DB is used to get the file automatically

Comment: You may misunderstand my question. I have already used this code and I can upload files. The problem is, the modified time of the file is changed to the transferred time. I want to keep the original modified time.